# How to determine IP address of guest operating system in qemu?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, kvm, dhcp, qemu

After I boot a Windows XP in qemu it gets an IP assigned from DHCP server. My question is - how do I determine the IP that Windows XP got assigned, so that I can connect to Windows XP?

Here are more details about my setup:

I run `dnsmasq` on tun0 interface. I've set it up to give IPs from range 10.10.10.0/24. I use `-net tun` for qemu. I run multiple Windows XP guest installations so I can't use static IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The generic approach is to have [Qemu Guest Agent](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/interop/qemu-ga.html) and run a specific command, [guest-network-get-interaces](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/interop/qemu-ga-ref.html#qapidoc-124) to obtain its network settings.

For this to work you need to add a guest agent socket into the VM configuration first. Qemu needs to be run in the way similar to this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 ... \
 -device virtio-serial,id=qga0 \
 -device virtserialport,chardev=qga0,name=org.qemu.guest_agent.0 \
 -chardev socket,path=base.qga,server=on,wait=off,id=qga0 \
...
```

This will create a socket file `base.qga` in the current directory. Then you may connect to this socket using `socat`, but for convenience (command line editing and history) I'd suggest to wrap it with `rlwrap`:

```
rlwrap socat STDIO UNIX:base.qga
```

In the guest OS you should install serial VirtIO (paravirtual) driver and the guest agent service, both are supplied in the form of virtio drivers ISO image. You can obtain it from Fedora VirtIO Windows drivers project; in Linux OS it is available in distribution repos in all major distros or you can build it yourself from Qemu source.

Guest agent is a powerful way to communicate between host (hypervisor) and the VM, other virtualization technologies also provide agents for similar integration functionality (e.g. VMWare Additions, VirtualBox Additions). With Qemu Guest Agent you may not only get various information about the guest, but also run some commands and set up inside it. Proxmox VE, which is based on Debian and Qemu, also uses its guest agent to make disk freeze before taking backups and for other enterprise-grade features.

Answer (score 0):

The list of dnsmasq's leases is stored in a file that is specified in the configuration option `dhcp-leasefile`. For the upstream version, the default location is `/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases`.

Comment: It doesn't look like a good approach. There are no guarantees about this files consistency. I boot up 20-40 qemu instances at a time. It's not clear what the race conditions are and how to determine which qemu instance got which ips.

Comment: @bodacydo, you'd derive the IP address based on the Mac address of the interface of your VM

Comment: I can't trust this solution. What if dnsmasq crashes at any point and overwrites the file. What if file content changes while it's being read. What if VM reboots and gets a new IP while I was still reading the content of the file. This is not a good engineering solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you start it you know the host name.  With that you query your (proprerly configured of course) dns. It is DNSmasq after all.

Comment: There are no hostnames, it's all ipv4 based. I've to downvote your answer it's poorly written and doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Try a    host <ip address> @127.0.0.1    you will be surprised.

Comment: I don't know <ip address> in the first place. That's what this is all about. If I knew <ip address> then I wouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Here's what I have: I've dnsmasq running on 10.10.10.1 (tap0). A qemu VM boots up and runs dhcp client that gets an IP from dnsmasq running on the host. I don't know the IP that VM gets.

Comment: If I remember correctly, DNSmasq logs in /var/log/syslog. Find your ip address once and do the host command,  really.

Comment: Why do the host command when I've the IP? That's all I needed. The IP.

Comment: Because it shows you the hostname of the guest.

Comment: @bodacydo would you mind upvoting my answer please?